# ¿Como encriptar y desencriptar un archivo con AES-256 en vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, criptografía

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño software que sea capaz de encriptar archivos, investigando un poco encontré recomendaciones para usar el algoritmo AES-256 pero lo malo es que aun no encuentro ningún ejemplo de alguna función para encriptar lo que es un archivo con dicho algoritmo.

¿Alguien podría compartirme algunas funciones de encriptar y desencriptar con dicho algoritmo? Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

> Esta pregunta fue respondida aqui:
>
> - [Standard library for AES encryption for VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16421817/8933039) por [Steven Doggart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1359668/steven-doggart)

El espacio de nombres `System.Security.Cryptography` contiene todas las clases que necesita para realizar la mayoría de las tareas de cifrado estándar. Desafortunadamente, dado que el cifrado es un tema bastante complicado, las clases son algo difíciles de trabajar, especialmente para principiantes. A veces es difícil encontrar un ejemplo de trabajo simple para empezar. Pero, dado que soy amable, te ofreceré un ejemplo simple con el que puedes jugar y mejorar :)

La clase que probablemente quiera usar se llama `RijndaelManaged`. Esa es la clase que implementa el típico cifrado `AES`. Aquí hay una clase de muestra que usa eso para convertir cadenas de texto sin formato y matrices de bytes:

```
Public Class Aes256Encrypter
    Public Function Encrypt(ByVal plainText As String, ByVal secretKey As String) As Byte()
        Dim encryptedPassword As Byte()
        Using outputStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
            Dim algorithm As RijndaelManaged = getAlgorithm(secretKey)
            Using cryptoStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(outputStream, algorithm.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                Dim inputBuffer() As Byte = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText)
                cryptoStream.Write(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length)
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
                encryptedPassword = outputStream.ToArray()
            End Using
        End Using
        Return encryptedPassword
    End Function

    Public Function Decrypt(ByVal encryptedBytes As Byte(), ByVal secretKey As String) As String
        Dim plainText As String = Nothing
        Using inputStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(encryptedBytes)
            Dim algorithm As RijndaelManaged = getAlgorithm(secretKey)
            Using cryptoStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(inputStream, algorithm.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                Dim outputBuffer(0 To CType(inputStream.Length - 1, Integer)) As Byte
                Dim readBytes As Integer = cryptoStream.Read(outputBuffer, 0, CType(inputStream.Length, Integer))
                plainText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(outputBuffer, 0, readBytes)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return plainText
    End Function

    Private Function getAlgorithm(ByVal secretKey As String) As RijndaelManaged
        Const salt As String = "put your salt here"
        Const keySize As Integer = 256

        Dim keyBuilder As Rfc2898DeriveBytes = New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(secretKey, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt))
        Dim algorithm As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged()
        algorithm.KeySize = keySize
        algorithm.IV = keyBuilder.GetBytes(CType(algorithm.BlockSize / 8, Integer))
        algorithm.Key = keyBuilder.GetBytes(CType(algorithm.KeySize / 8, Integer))
        algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
        Return algorithm
    End Function
End Class
```

Deberías cambiar la constante `salt` por otra cosa. Idealmente, ni siquiera sería una constante, ya que, para que sea lo más seguro posible, debe usar una sal diferente cada vez que realice el cifrado, pero ese es un tema totalmente distinto.

Si desea que el valor encriptado se devuelva como una cadena en lugar de una matriz de bytes, puede usar la codificación Base-64 para convertir la matriz de bytes a cadenas y desde cadenas como esta:

```
Public Class Aes256Base64Encrypter
    Public Function Encrypt(ByVal plainText As String, ByVal secretKey As String) As String
        Dim encryptedPassword As String = Nothing
        Using outputStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
            Dim algorithm As RijndaelManaged = getAlgorithm(secretKey)
            Using cryptoStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(outputStream, algorithm.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                Dim inputBuffer() As Byte = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText)
                cryptoStream.Write(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length)
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
                encryptedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(outputStream.ToArray())
            End Using
        End Using
        Return encryptedPassword
    End Function

    Public Function Decrypt(ByVal encryptedBytes As String, ByVal secretKey As String) As String
        Dim plainText As String = Nothing
        Using inputStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedBytes))
            Dim algorithm As RijndaelManaged = getAlgorithm(secretKey)
            Using cryptoStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(inputStream, algorithm.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                Dim outputBuffer(0 To CType(inputStream.Length - 1, Integer)) As Byte
                Dim readBytes As Integer = cryptoStream.Read(outputBuffer, 0, CType(inputStream.Length, Integer))
                plainText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(outputBuffer, 0, readBytes)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return plainText
    End Function

    Private Function getAlgorithm(ByVal secretKey As String) As RijndaelManaged
        Const salt As String = "put your salt here"
        Const keySize As Integer = 256

        Dim keyBuilder As Rfc2898DeriveBytes = New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(secretKey, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt))
        Dim algorithm As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged()
        algorithm.KeySize = keySize
        algorithm.IV = keyBuilder.GetBytes(CType(algorithm.BlockSize / 8, Integer))
        algorithm.Key = keyBuilder.GetBytes(CType(algorithm.KeySize / 8, Integer))
        algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
        Return algorithm
    End Function
End Class
```

Si está almacenando el valor cifrado en un archivo de texto, XML o incluso una base de datos, a menudo es más fácil usar Base-64, así.

Comment: ¿Como seria pero en el caso de un archivo y no texto plano? Pues el code que adjuntaste hace referencia a texto plano.

Comment: Pues mira esto: [Cifrar / descifrar archivos en VB.NET (usando Rijndael)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12092/Encrypt-Decrypt-Files-in-VB-NET-Using-Rijndael)